# Adding rows in data frame for prediction using time series

Tags: r

I have data frame with 32 rows. I want to add 5 more rows with dates appending as shown in data. i will put my time series prediction in the place of NA's. Can anyone help how to add the 5 rows with date appending in the data frame.
PFA Code for creating Data Frame in R

```
zz <- "parts    country_code    Week_Start  Qty part_country
SLX01121X00 VN  10/15/2017  2   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  10/22/2017  2   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  10/29/2017  1   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  11/5/2017   3   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  11/12/2017  5   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  11/19/2017  4   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  11/26/2017  2   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  12/3/2017   8   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  12/10/2017  13  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  12/17/2017  5   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  12/24/2017  3   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  12/31/2017  10  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  1/7/2018    6   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  1/14/2018   6   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  1/21/2018   11  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  1/28/2018   11  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  2/4/2018    11  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  2/11/2018   3   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  2/18/2018   3   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  2/25/2018   10  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  3/4/2018    3   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  3/11/2018   8   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  3/18/2018   7   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  3/25/2018   4   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  4/1/2018    6   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  4/8/2018    10  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  4/15/2018   7   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  4/22/2018   6   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  4/29/2018   11  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  5/6/2018    16  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  5/13/2018   16  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  5/20/2018   6   SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  5/27/2018   NA  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  6/3/2018    NA  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  6/10/2018   NA  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  6/17/2018   NA  SLX01121X00_VN
SLX01121X00 VN  6/24/2018   NA  SLX01121X00_VN"
```

Read the data

```
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbind`

```
rbind(Data,
      c(parts = "SLX01121X00",
        country_code = "VN",
        Week_Start = "5/27/2017",
        Qty = NA,
        part_country = "SLX01121X00_VN")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response But i have to add this in loop for many part country_code combinations

Comment: @siddharthsingh: can't understand what that means. You mean your dataframe is really much longer than the 32-row snippet, contains many different `part_country` values, and you want to append 5 blank rows in each? If so, please look up `dplyr` package and `group_by`, try to use it, then edit your question if you get stuck.